# How can I remove everything after a word on every line of a text file?

Tags: replace, editor

I have a text file that looks a bit like this

```
356, http://linkgoeshere.com/4445555 title="The Chariot"> <br />
356, http://linkgoeshere.com/4445555 title="fddsfssfd"> <br />
356, http://linkgoeshere.com/4445555 title="T3434534535"> <br />
```

I want to just leave everything up to the link and remove everything after but each part after is unique apart from the title= so I can't do find and replace.

(About 800 lines of this btw)

Is there any way I can do this using programming?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify the description, so is this the kind of output line you want?         `356, http://linkgoeshere.com/4445555`

Answer (score 1):

In `Notepad++` you can do this with find and replace using Regular expression

- Click menu `Search --> Replace...`
- In `Search Mode` select `Regular expression`
- Enter the regular expression `\stitle=".*$` in `Find what`
- Make `Replace with` box empty
- Click `Replace all`

Tested in version `6.2.2`

This should also work in other editors supporting find and replace using Regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

- **Editor** way (vim):

open your file with vim, type `:%s/ title=.$//g` you would have seen the result.

in fact any Editor supports regex replace would work.

- script programming:

**sed**

(note:the command below will make the change in place.)

```
sed -i 's/ title=.$//' file
```

**awk**:

tricky way, without regex:

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' file
```

you see the output on stdout. you could redirect it to a file by `awk... >newFile`

Answer (score -1):

**Excel**
If your editor doesn't support regular expressions, use Excel to import the file as a csv file (Data -> From Text) and tell excel to use the space as field delimiter. Then export the first two columns as a new csv file.